# *** glibc detected *** free(): invalid pointer:

Tags: c++, glibc

I'm completely stumped as to the cause of the above glibc error. I must be missing something obvious, but it appears every time the following program (consisting of 4 files) exits:

TankSim.h:

```
#ifndef TANKSIM_WDECAY_TANKSIM_H_
#define TANKSIM_WDECAY_TANKSIM_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include "Parser.h"

int main();

#endif
```

TankSim.cpp:

```
#include "TankSim.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
     const Settings gGlobals = ParseConfig();

     return(0);
}
```

Parser.h:

```
#ifndef TANKSIM_WDECAY_PARSER_H_
#define TANKSIM_WDECAY_PARSER_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

struct Settings {
  double speedlight;
  double refractiveindex;
  double absorptionchance;
  double pmtradius;
  double photspermetre;
  double tankradius;
  double tankheight;
  long unsigned int randomseed;
  double scatterangle;
  std::vector<double> entrypoint;
  std::vector<double> entrydrn;
};

Settings ParseConfig();

#endif
```

Parser.cpp:

```
#include "Parser.h"

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

Settings ParseConfig()
{
  Settings settings;

  std::ifstream configfile("settings.dat");

  string line;
  while(getline(configfile,line)){
    //Comments start with %
    if(line.find("%") != string::npos){
      cout << "Comment: " << line << endl;
      continue;
    }

    //Read in variable name.
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << line;
    string varname;
    ss >> varname;
    string value = line.substr(varname.length()+1);
    cout << varname << "-" << value << endl;
  }
}
```

Since I'm not explicitly calling any delete operators, I have no idea why the error occurs.

Comment: where is the return statement?

Comment: @BobFincheimer - that's what I was thinking - should be returning a 'Settings'.

Comment: Oh dear. Thanks very much - I'm not having a good day today!

Comment: @Wheels2050 please accept if this was indeed the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely its the missing return statement.

Then in your main method the `Settings` local object is never initialized.  Then its scope ends and the destructor for the vectors in it are called and they think they have a pointer (because they are initialized with junk in memory) and call delete on their pointer.

Adding `-Wall` to enable all warnings will tell you about this in the future.